# Rotate cloned object 90 degrees

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I create object +10 sign when player shot enemy

I need to rotate this sign 90 degrees from enemy object

I use code below , but it  still not working

```
private void plus_score(){
    Quaternion spawnRotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, 90);
    Instantiate( Score_object ,gameObject.transform.position ,spawnRotation);
}
```

any suggestion to rotate my clone object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to rotate this sign 90 degree from enemy object

You multiply Quaternions together to rotate them.

```
private void plus_score(){
    Quaternion spawanRotation = enemy.transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, 90);
    Instantiate( Score_object ,gameObject.transform.position ,spawanRotation);
}
```